Prove that $Z_n$ is independent of $(Y_{i,n})_i$
Suppose we have $Y_{i,n},  i \ge 1, n \ge 1 $ iid with expectation $\mu$. And given $Z_{n+1} = \sum_{i=1} ^{Z_n} Y_{i,n}$ and $Z_0 = 1$.
In lecture it was stated that $Y_{i,n}$ is independent of $Z_n$. I do not see how one would prove that.
In particular we therefore used Wald's equation to obtain:
$E[Z_{n+1}] = E[Z_n] E[Y_{1,n}]$.
I would be glad if someone could explain to me why $Z_n$ is independent of $Y_{i,n}$ or if there is a different argument justifying $E[Z_{n+1}] = E[Z_n] E[Y_{1,n}]$.
Edit: The context was that $Z_n$ could be interpreted as the number of individuals in a generation and $Y_{i,n}$ as the number of children that individual $i$ in generation $n$ has.

Can you see that $Z_n$ is a function of $Y_{i,j}$ for $j < n$?  (or more precisely, $Z_n$ is $\sigma(Y_{i,j} : i \geq 1, 1\leq j \leq n-1)$-measurable)

Yes, I see that

And can you see that $(Y_{i,n})i$ is independent of $\sigma(Y{i,j} : i \geq 1, 1 \leq j \leq n-1)$?

Is it independent since all $Y_{i,n}$ are independent?

I need to be a little careful with the subscripts, but essentially yes, since the entire 2d array $Y_{i,j}$ for $i \geq 1, j \geq 1$ are iid, the sigma algebras generated by any two disjoint subsets of this array will be independent.

So now, we have that $Z_n$ is a function of $Y_{i,j}$ for $j<n$ and $1 \leq i \leq Z_{n-1}$. Implying it is also a function of $Z_{n-1}$ however $Z_{n-1}$ can again be substituted as function of $Y_{i,j}$ for $j<n-1$ continuing this process we obtain a function only of $Y_{i,j}$'s. However, I do not see why this implies that $Z_n$ is independent of $Y_{i,n}$

Oh I see, $Z_n$ is a function of $Y_{i,j}$ for $1 \leq j \leq n-1$. And the $Y_{i,j}$ for $1 \leq j \leq n-1$ are independent of $Y_{i,n}$. Thank you very much for guiding me to the solution!

First, note that $Z_n$ is $\sigma(Z_{n-1}, Y_{1,n-1}, Y_{2,n-1}, \ldots)$-measurable.
By induction on $n$, this shows that $Z_n$ is $\sigma(Y_{i,j} : i\geq 1, 1\leq j < n)$-measurable.
It now suffices to show that $\sigma(Y_{i,n} : i\geq 1)$ is independent of $\sigma(Y_{i,j} : i\geq 1, 1\leq j < n)$.  However, this follows directly from the assumption that the 2D-array $(Y_{i,j})_{i\geq 1, \, j\geq 1}$ is an array of independent random variables, since the second subscript of the random variables generating $\sigma(Y_{i,n} : i\geq 1)$ is always $n$, which is larger than any of the second subscripts of the random variables generating $\sigma(Y_{i,j} : i\geq 1, 1\leq j < n)$.

Thank you very much!

do you happen to know a rigoruous proof for why the sigma-algebras are independ because the random variables are different and independent?
